# Create array from ahref links inside a user generated li list

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am writing a program and in that program users can drag/drop .wav files into a playlist-container. Then they can play all these files into the order they are in the playlist-container. Now I am making the save function that combines all these .wav files into one file and saves this into a specific folder. But I am currently stuck on retrieving all the files that are into the playlist-container.

Below I am posting the most relevant codes:

When a user has added a few items into the playlist it looks like this:

```
<ul class="playlist-container connectedSortable links ui-sortable pt-container">
 <li class="audiofile im franklin 0x048209BE ui-sortable-handle" id="[franklin]_[0x048209BE]_im.wav" style="position: relative; left: 0px; top: 0px;">
   <a href="audio/[franklin]_[0x048209BE]_im.wav" class="mainaudiolink pt-link" target="audiotesting" data-pushtape-index="0"></a>
 </li>
 <li class="audiofile following franklin 0x048209BE ui-sortable-handle" id="[franklin]_[0x048209BE]_following.wav" style="position: relative; left: 0px; top: 0px;">
   <a href="audio/[franklin]_[0x048209BE]_following.wav" class="mainaudiolink pt-link" target="audiotesting" data-pushtape-index="1"></a>
 </li>
 <li class="audiofile mike franklin 0x048209BE ui-sortable-handle" id="[franklin]_[0x048209BE]_mike.wav" style="position: relative; left: 0px; top: 0px;">
   <a href="audio/[franklin]_[0x048209BE]_mike.wav" class="mainaudiolink pt-link" target="audiotesting" data-pushtape-index="2"></a>
 </li>
</ul>
```

Now I tested succesfully the combining(joining) of the script by hardcoding it like this:

```
<?php
//Select wav files
$wStart = "../audio/[spacer]_[tools]_onesecond.wav";
$wEnd = "../audio/[spacer]_[tools]_onesecond.wav";
$w1 = "../audio/[franklin]_[0x048209BE]_following.wav";
$w2 = "../audio/[franklin]_[0x048209BE]_an.wav";
$w3 = "../audio/[franklin]_[0x048209BE]_architect.wav";

//load wav files
$wFiles = array($wStart,$w1,$w2,$w3,$wEnd);
?>
```

Now the question I got how can I make it that it retrieves it from the playlist-container so that I get something like this:

```
<?php
//Select wav files
$wStart = "../audio/[spacer]_[tools]_onesecond.wav";
$wEnd = "../audio/[spacer]_[tools]_onesecond.wav";
$wRetrievedAudioFiles = '"File1" . "File2" etc';


//load wav files
$wFiles = array($wStart,$wRetrievedAudioFiles,$wEnd);
?>
```

PS: I know the last piece of code can't possibly work in the way it is written down but I do hope that it is clear what I try to achieve.
PS2: I forgot to mention that the HTML part is in a file called index.php in the root. The joining of the wavs happens via the file `ROOT/audio_saved/wavedit.php`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$files = scandir ('../audio/'); // gets all files`

Now filter out the ones that make sense
`$files = array_filter($files, function ($f) {
   return preg_match('/\[franklin\]_\[0x048209BE\].*\.wav/', $f);}) === 1;`

Need to add back in the directory prefix
`$files = array_map(function ($f) { return '../audio/'.$f; }, $files);`

Last, add the spacer wav file to the beginning and end

`$files[] = '../audio/[spacer]_[tools]_onesecond.wav';
array_unshift($files, '../audio/[spacer]_[tools]_onesecond.wav');`

`$files` should have what you need although I didn't test the code here.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I don't see a point of scanning the audio folder that contains over 20000 items of audio. Then the next part assumes that I know what to filter for but users generate those playlists. The playlist in my example merely is a example. Or am I missing something :-)

Comment: This sounds like exactly the kind of problem databases were invented to solve. Not sure how to help since I clearly don't understand your problem as it is currently described.

Comment: On a page all the audio files are loaded into a div (they are words) now users can drag & drop these words from this div into a playlist-container. Then they can play the playlist. Now I want to create a button that saves all the words the user posted into the playlist-container into one .wav file. 

So basically on save button click: Get all the audio files into the playlist container. Put those all into 1 variable like this `"File1","File2","Etc"` and that is it.

Sadly a database is out of the question for this type of application.

Comment: So you are trying to figure out on the frontend how to get those values?

Comment: Perhaps `$('.playlist-container li').each( function () { console.log($(this).find('a').attr('href'));});` will spit those values out for you. If so then change console.log to some array push, or string concat as you please and send that variable to the backend for processing

Comment: I am so sorry for this late response. Thank you very much for that last replies. Yes indeed I am trying to get those values thru the frontend. Going to try out your log trick. Good idea btw. I also figured out I had a issue because I was searching for values that where not present in the file because I forgotten to include it :-) Will let you know if I get it working. Thanks again and have a great day.